# the provided uri scheme https is invalid; expected 'http' in app.config

Tags: wcf, https

I have a wcf with like below url

> https://localhost:44370/service.svc

I have a window service which is using the above wcf

and in my app.config I configured the same like below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://localhost:44370/service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IService" contract="FileServer.IService"
          name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

but I am getting the following error the provided uri scheme https is invalid; expected 'http'

when I changed my binding type into https like below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpsBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://localhost:44370/service.svc" binding="basicHttpsBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IService" contract="FileServer.IService"
          name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

then I am getting the below error

configuration binding extension 'system.servicemodel/binding.basichttpsbinding' could not be found. verify that this binding extension is properly registered in 'system.servicemodel/binding.basichttpsbinding' and that it is spelled correctly.

what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a HTTPS address with a HTTP binding, change the binding type to 'basicHttpsBinding'.

Comment: updated my question for your reference

Comment: anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

> but I am getting the following error the provided uri scheme https is
> invalid; expected 'http'

You try adding security mode to the binding, this change will allow you to use https instead of http.

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport"> 
      </security> 
    </binding> 
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:  unrecognized element 'security'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change when I copied your code, `security mode` needs to be in `binding`, I have changed the answer.